# Responsive layout with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to make my first page. I'm learning coding but I have problems with a responsive display. I'm making with Bootstrap, I want to make my layout responsive in all way.

But this is hard for me as I'm starting and learning to code.

```css
 .fromtop{
  padding-top: 30px;
 }
 @media (max-width: 767px){
  .fromtop{
  padding: 0px;
  } } 
.circle{
border-radius: 50%;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
background: red;
color: white;
}
@media (max-width: 1199px){
  .circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
width: 230px;
height: 230px;
background: red;
color: white;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px){
  .circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
width: 210px;
height: 210px;
background: red;
color: white;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 850px){
  .circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
width: 190px;
height: 190px;
background: red;
color: white;
  }
}
.text-inner {
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
}
.number{
font-size: 110px;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 89px;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .number{
    font-size: 110px;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
  } }
  @media (max-width: 421px) {
  .number-3{
    font-size: 110px;
width: 100%;
margin-top: -50px;
  } }
.middle{
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.white-text{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
}
.nop{
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.totop{
  margin-top: -45px;
}
.arrow{
margin-top: 100px;
}
.under-number {
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
    <section class="well-md bg-white white">
            <div class="container inset-6">
                <h2 class="text-bold text-center red">Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3">
                <div class="circle">
                <p class="number text-bold text-inner">1.</p>
                <p class="text-bold under-number">Lorem</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="text-left col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-9">
                        <h3 class="text-bold big-grey goright">Lorem ipsum</h3>
                        <p class="grey goright">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tristique mattis arcu a ullamcorper. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In a nibh a urna condimentum aliquet egestas sed nulla. Sed molestie ligula id enim placerat suscipit. Sed sit amet semper purus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="images/arrow.png">
                <div class="row totop">
                    <div class="text-right col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                        <h3 class="text-bold big-grey">Lorem ipsum</h3>
                        <p class="grey">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tristique mattis arcu a ullamcorper. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In a nibh a urna condimentum aliquet egestas sed nulla. Sed molestie ligula id enim placerat suscipit. Sed sit amet semper purus.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="circle">
                <p class="number text-bold text-inner">2.</p>
                <p class="text-bold under-number">Lorem</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <img src="images/arrow2.png" class="pull-right">
                <div class="row arrow">
                 <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="circle">
                <p class="number text-bold text-inner number-3">3.</p>
                <p class="text-bold under-number">Lorem</p>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="text-left col-md-9">
                        <h3 class="text-bold big-grey goright">Lorem ipsum</h3>
                        <p class="grey goright">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tristique mattis arcu a ullamcorper. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In a nibh a urna condimentum aliquet egestas sed nulla. Sed molestie ligula id enim placerat suscipit. Sed sit amet semper purus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: You need to specify what exactly your problem is and what you need help with.  The problem specified as it is is too vague.

Comment: We have no idea what your page is supposed to look like on mobile, tablet, desktop etc.

Comment: Do you have any design in mind? Or at least a layout for us to help you with the Bootstrap way of grid system? I can already see you have messed with Bootstrap grid system